# How do you keep an input string from printing if you have not told it to print

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you keep an input string from printing if you have not told it to print.
This:

```
class o():
    row = int(input("Select number > "))
```

will print out 'Select number even if i have not told it to print.

and this:

```
class o():
def select(self,row):
    row = int(input("Select number > "))

pracObj = o()
o.select(self,row)
```

will give me an error.

and if I place the input outside the class it still prints.

Comment: If you don't want `Select number > ` to print just do `row = int(input())`

Answer (score 1):

The `input` function will print whatever you have in quotes. To have it "not print anything" you just need to call it without any text.

```
row = int(input())
```

To get your behavior of sometimes printing, you can split it up like this

```
if wantToPrint:  # where wantToPrint is some bool
    print("Select number >")
row = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Try this:

```
class o():
    def select(self):
        row = int(input('Number > '))
        return row

pracObj = o()
row = pracObj.select()
print(row)
```

You create an instance of the class with

```
pracObj = o()
```

Now, pracObj is the instance, and you can access its methods as you please:

```
row = pracObj.select()
```

will `return` the value of the `input` to the variable `row`.